# How do you perform wireless debugging in Xcode 9 with iOS 11? without passcode

Tags: ios, debugging, ipad, ios11, xcode9

Is there any possibility to perform wireless debugging without using passcode, because i don't want to set passcode for my iPad due to some critical reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't like to set a passcode on my test devices either, huge pain in the butt to unlock it every time I run an app from Xcode.

They make you install a passcode to turn on Wireless testing. Then it won't install wirelessly because it says the device is locked and you must unlock it first...Arghhhh

But what you can do is turn on a passcode, setup the wireless transferring in "Devices" and then remove your passcode from you device and viola! it automatically sends to my iPhone without any interruptions and without a passcode.

Comment: This seems to no longer works plainly, you have to now reconnect one more time after removing passcode and enable the wireless testing setting once again, then it works.